# Blogdown - window to stage and commit changes no longer appears

Tags: github, blogdown

I recently created a website using blogdown and now hosting it on a GitHub repository and netlify to deploy. When I set it up, I followed the directions to clone my GitHub repository to be able to commit files using the git version control. So making changes within Rmarkdown and then committing them to my GitHub repository was easy.

However, when I connect to the project now, the window where I can commit changes does not appear. That is, I no longer have the option to commit changes within R studio. My guess is that the connection between the terminal and GitHub was changed/removed? Does anyone know how to re-establish this? I've looked up the syntax to use in the terminal, but I couldn't find a similar problem - that is, re-establish the connection between my GitHub with an already existing project already on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer to this question in the case others have a problem. It was an issue with MojaveOS. You have to re-install command line tools in the terminal.

xcode-select --install

Doing this, the version control now works to commit files to my github repository.